# can't get array to display correctly on the website

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm trying to do is make a search function for a list of a lot of products.
The way the products work is that each product has a product_parent and a product_index
the product_parent saves information about the product itself, and product_index saves the "sku" for the products , and when calling for all the procuts I use this code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = ['DISCOUNT;;Discount',
        <?php   
                $get_con2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product_parents`");
                    $conarr2 = array();
                    while($con2 = mysql_fetch_array($get_con2)){
                        array_push($conarr2,$con2['id']);
                    }
                $get_con = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product_childs` WHERE `parent_id` IN (".implode(',',$conarr2).")");
                    $conarr = array();
                    while($con = mysql_fetch_array($get_con)){
                        array_push($conarr,$con['index_id']);
                    }
                    $showall = "WHERE `id` IN (".implode(",",$conarr).")";              

                $get_prods = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product_index`".$showall);
                $get_brand = mysql_query("SELECT product_parents.supplier, suppliers.id, suppliers.name FROM product_parents WHERE LEFT JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.id=product_parents.supplier");
                $get_prodname = mysql_query("SELECT product_parents.name FROM product_parents");
                $js = "";
                while($prods = mysql_fetch_array($get_prods)){
                    $prodbrand = mysql_fetch_array($get_brand);
                    $prodname = mysql_fetch_array($get_prodname);
                    /* $js .= "'". addslashes($prodbrand['name'])."". addslashes($prodname['name'])." (".indexStock($prods['id'])." on stock);;".addslashes($prods['sku'])."',"; */
                    /* $js .= "'".addslashes($prods['sku']).";; ". addslashes($prods['name'])." (".indexStock($prods['id'])." on stock)',"; */

                    $js .= "'".addslashes($prodbrand['name'])."',";
                    /* $js .= "'".addslashes($prodbrand['name'])." ".addslashes($prodname['name']).";; ". addslashes($prods['name'])." (".indexStock($prods['id'])." on stock)',"; */
                } echo substr($js,0,-1);
        ?>
    ];
    $( "#add_row_sku" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });

});
</script>
```

and it's showing a bunch of results, but not all of them, however when I run the query in phpmyadmin it results every result I am trying to have it show.
also, when I use:

```
/* $js .= "'".addslashes($prods['sku']).";; ". addslashes($prods['name'])." (".indexStock($prods['id'])." on stock)',"; */
```

it shows things just fine, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? I've been stuck for hours. also if you are willing to help but don't quite understand what I'm asking, I'll be happy to add you on skype or whatever so you can further assist me and that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do all 3 result sets $get_prods, $get_brand, $get_prodname have the same row counts? You're looping over $get_prods only so it would be limited to that count regardless of what is in $get_prodname.

Comment: They don't all have the same row counts and right now I am not using $get_prodname at all. it's just there for when I get $get_prodbrand working correctly, but as I said, $get_prods does result in all the products being echoed into the array, but they don't show the product brands, which is a must for this to work as it's supposed to. so what I'm trying to do is have $get_brand result in the same amount of arrays as $get_prods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. You can make your life easier by using json_encode to create the javascript.  Build out the array in PHP and it handles any addslashes or encoding.  I had to rename some of the variables as it made it hard to read.  $rs is result set, $row is well table row. I prefer the $array[] syntax vs .push

```
<?php
  $availableTags = array('DISCOUNT;;Discount');

  // Get product parents and their supplier
  $sql = "SELECT product_parents.id, product_parents.name as parent_name, suppliers.name as supplier_name FROM `product_parents` LEFT JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.id=product_parents.supplier";
  $rs = mysql_query($sql);
  $parents = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    $parents[$row['id']] = $row;
  }

  // Get all product childs whatever that means
  $sql = "SELECT index_id, parent_id FROM `product_childs` WHERE `parent_id` IN (" . implode(',', array_keys($parents)). ")";
  $rs = mysql_query($sql);
  $childs = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $childs[$row['index_id']] = $row['parent_id'];
  }

  // Get all the products
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `product_index` WHERE `id` IN (" . implode(",", array_keys($childs)) .")";
  $rs = mysql_query($sql);

  while($prods = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $availableTags[] = $prods['name'];
    $availableTags[] = $prods['sku'];
    $parentId = $childs[$prods['id']];
    $brand = $parents[$parentId]['supplier_name'];
    $parentName = $parents[$parentId]['parent_name'];
    $availableTags[] = $brand;
  }

?>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($availableTags); ?>
    $( "#add_row_sku" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: I just tried this and it returns no results at all.

Comment: Might have to do a little debugging.  I changed to put the SQL statements in a variable can echo $sql and try them out in mysql.  Could be minor error there.  Also use print_r($parents) or print_r($childs) to see if those are correct. Hopefully there are not thousands of rows. Hard to know what's wrong without knowing the full database structure

Comment: print_r did print everything out, seems like it's not creating the availibletags correctly then.
however using this: var availableTags = ['hello',<?php echo json_encode($availableTags); ?>]; does return hello as a result but nothing else.

Comment: That's odd it should at least have 'DISCOUNT;;Discount' in it which is put in as the first element.  print_r($availableTags) has nothing in it?  Did all the SQL statements run on mysql?

Comment: aaaalright, a little changing around and I got it to work. I just used my old method of addslashes and substr($js,0,-1); to echo the tags and it worked, didn't get the supplier names though, noticed you just did a tiny typo in $brand = $parents[$parendId]['supplier_name'];